# C# floating point number's precision of display and calculation, which are different

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am doing calculation by C# on Win7.

I got a double number precision problem.

```
 double x = 3389774.583;

 string ss = "x is " + x + " x square is " + x * x + " , 11490571723552.8 - x*x is " + (11490571723552.8 - x * x) + "\n";

 Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

you may find the result is not 0 even tough 11490571723552.8 is the x*x.

I know it is the precision problem of display and calculation.

I can set up a threshold to make the result 0.

Are there other better ways ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `decimal` instead of `double`. It has smaller range, but the precision is much better.

Comment: Have a look at the many questions about floating point precision in the "Related" bar at the lower-right side of this question.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

it's because square of 3389774.583 is not 11490571723552.8.
If you will try windows calculator you will get value around 11490571723552.823889.

So there is no chance to get result 0 for  (11490571723552.8 - x * x) where x is 3389774.583

Try

```
double x = 3389774.583;
double xx = x*x;
Console.WriteLine(xx); 

string ss = "x is " + x + " x square is " + x * x + " , 11490571723552.8 - x*x is " + (xx - x * x) + "\n";
Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rounding the output to a number of decimals with a [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) string:

```
Console.WriteLine(ss.ToString("F2"));
```